# How to boot ubuntu from my sd card

Tags: installation, boot, sd-card

I want to try ubuntu, so I put it on my sd card 32 card. But I can't figure out how to boot from my sd card from my boot menu. My sdcard usb drive is too outdated i got in 2005 and it only Support sc not sdhc my sd card is a class 6 32 gb sdhc. and my computer is a dell inspiron n7110.

Please help me.

Comment: Reverse engineer your card/adapter, get a USB adapter for the SD card.

Comment: @ Andrew: According to the specs on the dell inspiron n7110 the SD card reader in the machine is compatible with SD, SDXC, and SDHC cards.  You might want to edit your question to remove the misleading information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the SD card.  Turn on the Dell, and when the BIOS screen appears press F12.

You will then get a list of devices to boot from.  Select the SD card and continue.

### Alternatives:

- Enter BIOS (probably F10) and change the boot order so
  that the SD card is the first device.
- Install Grub2 bootloader onto the hard drive.  It's quite capable of
  booting off the SD card.  This might be the best solution as you will
  always get the boot list (Windows or Ubuntu) and will not have to
  fiddle with BIOS or function keys.  To do this, install Ubuntu onto
  the SD card but make sure you install Grub to the first hard drive
  (advanced partitioner) in the setup programme.

Be very careful when using the advanced partitioner.  The hard drive will most likely be /dev/sda while the SD card may be /dev/sdb or something else if there is a separate card reader in the machine as well.

Comment: FYI I've written a guide about this approach on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD which may be useful.

Comment: @vorburger I have grub2  I read your guide (everything) but I wasn't able to follow the process, would you please make a little bit more for dummies?.

Comment: @fabricator4 I have Grub2, but I don't know how to make it recognize the SD Card or how to boot from there, would you please be a little bit more specific, I don't know if I am missing something there.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't use a SDHC card on a SD card reader that does not support SDHC. I had a similar problem and just bought a USB SDHC reader and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

An SD card should be reorganised as a USB drive or micro-USB or whatever but these old PC require a new BIOS manager like this "plop boot manager" to work. You can get it [here](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download). Hope this works! I'm going to see if it actually works!