# Booting Ubuntu from an SD card... Safe ?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, sd-card, chromebook

Is booting an OS off an SD card safe? I've been doing so for 2 weeks and so far no problems.

(I'm asking because I use a chromebook with Ubuntu 16.04 that boots off an SD card.)

Comment: Is it a live install or a full install?

Comment: Full install, also I was reading about how during the shutdown procedure the SD cards' electrical components can't flag the kernel during standard RW operations and the system is turned off pre maturely. Doing this multiple times will cause the disk to corrupt eventually. ... is this somewhat accurate ?

Comment: Can you post any links to where you read that? I'm hoping the system would finish a `sync` and `umount` filesystems before turning off, but watching my usb drives keep flashing after a `sync` makes me wonder... and some drives could conceivably report "all writes done" while internally still working, but hard drives and especially SSDs could do the same

Comment: I tried looking for it and I can't find it unfortunately... I'll edit this comment if I eventually find it (with the link attached)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing "unsafe" about using an SD as media for your OS. In fact that is the media most people used in the Raspberry PI v1 and 2. It will probably run significantly quicker than the standard mechanical HDD and isn't as sensitive to handling. The average expectancy for an SD under stand use is around 10 years, although there is a lot more read and write that goes when using it as an OS, so you can probably expect this to be significantly lower, around 5-7 years would probably be more accurate.

Comment: That's actually my main concern, there are exponentially more RW operations that go on if you mount an entire OS and I abuse this computer (I use it all day). I can only see it last 3 - 4 years (but that's just my guess). On another note the boot times and file transfers are super quick. I assumed this is because the RAM-like architecture of the SD card as opposed to the to relatively long seek times associated with standard HDD's.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely going to lower the life of the SD by using it in this fashion, as long as you backup any critical data regularly you shouldn't need to worry too much. It actually functions more like a SDD than RAM, due to the fact that memory is actually Non-volatile (persistent). I still don't see any issue with it as long as you back it up regularly. The life of the SD card will probably compare decently with any mechanical drive.

Comment: SD cards are generally slower than standard hard drives, not faster, as they are only optimized for sequential read/writes.

Comment: Back in the day when the only thing they were ever used for were cameras this is true, these days the amount of devices that use it to store critical system data has become so broad they are design more in line with msata ssd drives. A number of super micro enterprise class server use SD cards to store boot loader and media for core OS.

Comment: It also highly depends on the rating of card.  The highly-rated (UHS) cards are probably very similar to eMMC chips found in cheap laptops, while low-end/cheap cards (less than Class 10) will be VERY slow.  The card reader used also makes a difference.

Comment: I was reading about how during the shutdown procedure the SD cards' electrical components can't flag the kernel during standard RW operations and the system is turned off pre maturely. Doing this multiple times will cause the disk to corrupt eventually. ... is this somewhat accurate ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay spent the last 3 days over the weekend and on friday, looking at exactly this issue.

Like you this was a Ubuntu distribution. And like you this was a Chromebook. The Chromebook i was using was a Samsung ARM Series 3 Chromebook, XE303C12.

The version of ubuntu i was using was chromebook_snow-armv7l-jammy.img.
I also saw similar results on debian: chromebook_snow-armv7l-bullseye.img

I tested this with SD cards from high street stores. These were not SD cards i bought off ebay, amazon, or aliexpress. It is important for me to emphasize this because I want to rule out the possibility of second hand or counterfeit SD cards.

This is what i found:

Sandisk Ultra 30MB/s Class 10 SDHC 1 16GB cards would not boot at all. I tried this with 2 identical cards. Neither would boot. The Chromebook dropped me out consistently into a U-boot shell would not boot at all, it just didn't recognise it.

SanDisk Ultra 64GB Class 10 UHS 1 card. (C10, XC 1, A1, U1 64GB). This was a micro SD card in an adaptor card. This was bought some time ago, but i opened it in the last week specifically for the chromebook. I found issues with every single snow version of debian and ubuntu in the repository. Errors were random and erratic, the system always started to boot (unlike the Sandisk Ultra 30MB/s Class 10 SDHC 1 16GB cards which would never boot). Boot errors were random. Broadly speaking they fell into 3 categories:

1. Card corruption errors from rebooting the system due to hard lockups (see below):
2. Erratic and various issues with systemd services failing. These were non deterministic, and random things failed in unpredictable ways. Due to the services hierarchy in SystemD if certain key services fail to start up, that can block later services and this can cause: `systemd freezing execution` which is an unrecoverable error.
3. Intermittent stack traces and kernel panics.

I saw this behaviour consistently across Ubuntu and Debian.

Kingston 8GB Class 4 SDHC. This consistently started to boot, it kernel panicd a lot less than the SanDisk Ultra 64GB Class 10 UHS 1 Card. Typically the behaviour was different, there were stack traces in dmesg, but they didn't result in kernel panics, however i did see a lot of systemd failures resulting in `systemd freezing execution` errors.

Sandisk Ultra 80MB/s Class 10, SDHC 1, 16GB card. I had some success with this card. Behaviour was non deterministic and erratic. Debian consistently had issues with kernel panics, Ubuntu however did successfully boot. However, when it booted to X, I had some problems with the framebuffer driver restarting X. So I power cycled. On booting from this SD card a 2nd time, it didn't attempt to start X, but dropped me into a tty login, and i was able to get a bash terminal prompt which seemed to function.

After powering off the system. I had lunch and came back to it. I booted this SD card again, and I got a systemd failure. I powercycled again, and this time i got a journald failure - which i attribute to data corruption on the SD card caused by the filesystem being in some state when the system locked up.

I then went back to my server and created a new image on the same SD card, and tried again. This time i had kernel panics.

**In Summary:**

I've seen some systems work well booting off sd cards, e.g. rpi 2,3,4, parallellas etc. They tend to work for several weeks or if you disable swap and turn off anything that writes to the card often (in the end i used a read only fuse filesystem as this minimised writes to these devices), then you can get quite a lot of life out of an SD card. Invariably though, it's a matter of time before something is written to an SD card and a file gets corrupted in a critical place.

What I found however with my XE303C12 chromebook, was very different behaviour between SD cards. With some cards not being recognised at all, others seeing certain types of errors more than others. And I saw non deterministic behaviour.

This matches actually what other people have said about 503 and the 303 Samsung Chromebooks; they can be extremely fussy about the type of SD cards used in them.

In my case the answer to: "Booting Ubuntu from an SD card... Safe ?" for my Chromebook, absolutely not.

Comment: +1; Thanks for sharing your experience. I agree that this is not only due to the card, but also to the computer, some computers work better, when booted from a card. I have a Dell Latitude E7240 (with 4th generation Intel i5 processor), that behaves well running persistent live Lubuntu from a micro SD card via SD adapter and pci, so seen as device `/dev/mmcblk0`. It is a pretty old Sandisk Extreme Pro 32 GB HC. But I only test systems on it, I don't use it for 'production'. I have seen that many people have had sudden failures with SD cards, both with storage and with operating systems.

Comment: @sudodus I've spent so long on trying to get this chromebook running linux, i'm literally going to give up. Like i've setup pa-riscs, itaniums, all sorts of weird things, some of them i've had to connect rs232 to, some of them like sun microsystems need drives with 4K blocks, some computers wont work with screens unless they sync on green. I've seen some stuff. But the issues i've had over the last few days with SD cards and this particular chromebook takes the biscuit, it really does.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it safe?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQtM1syENmQ)

Yes, it's very safe. Here are the instructions from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191902/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-my-sd-card). They're referring to a Dell PC here but obviously the same basic ideas would apply.

> Insert the SD card. Turn on the Dell, and when the BIOS screen appears
>   press F12.
>
> You will then get a list of devices to boot from. Select the SD card
>   and continue.
>
> Alternatives:
>
> Enter BIOS (probably F10) and change the boot order so that the SD
>   card is the first device. Install Grub2 bootloader onto the hard
>   drive. It's quite capable of booting off the SD card. This might be
>   the best solution as you will always get the boot list (Windows or
>   Ubuntu) and will not have to fiddle with BIOS or function keys. To do
>   this, install Ubuntu onto the SD card but make sure you install Grub
>   to the first hard drive (advanced partitioner) in the setup programme.
>   Be very careful when using the advanced partitioner. The hard drive
>   will most likely be /dev/sda while the SD card may be /dev/sdb or
>   something else if there is a separate card reader in the machine as
>   well.

Comment: I've actully been booting Ubuntu 16.04 on my acer CB3-131 chromebook using a 128 gb SDXC card. The steps outlined are irrelevant but thanks anyways. My question is more along the lines of safety as in the number of RW operations that occur due to having an OS mounted on a SD card. I'm sure the life expectancy is jeopardized significantly

Comment: Not true actually.  You would have to install and uninstall a lot of programs to even put a dent into the (typically) over 50,000 write maximum most SD cards have these days.

Comment: If you are just running already installed programs, that has no effect on the read/write limits of your storage device because it will only be using your computer's RAM for temporary storage.

Comment: I was reading about how during the shutdown procedure the SD cards' electrical components can't flag the kernel during standard RW operations and the system is turned off pre maturely. Doing this multiple times will cause the disk to corrupt eventually. ... is this somewhat accurate ?

Comment: I have NO clue. I'm not an expert unfortunately.